# Check if program is using registry

Tags: windows, windows-registry

Can I somehow check if application has any registry entry? I want to know because when I move applications, I need to know if there will be any problem running it on another OS / PC.

Comment: You really shouldn't try to move applications unless they have been designed to be portable.  You should just reinstall them on the new machine.

Answer (score 0):

for the record.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx

Download and install
in the toolbar click all but the registry icon to deactivate the files/folders and etc.
You can add a filter to further narrow the output.

After that you can save the output to a file and run searches on it and find what you need.

This is a road of pain and suffer and I recommend re-installing.

Answer (score 0):

Use a virtual machine and [RegShot2](http://www.portablefreeware.com/index.php?id=2505) or [RegFromApp](http://www.portablefreeware.com/index.php?id=1433) to determine registry changes made during the install process or when changing program settings

You will get something like:
 [image]

As a downside these tools will list ALL changes made during the install process, but not all are caused by your program. Some of them are only irrelevant Windows things like the *Most recent used programs* list. Be aware of that